# kill-process doesn't kill process

Tags: process, kill-buffer

Why does the following sexp hang?

```
(let ((buf
          "*Async Shell Command*"))
     (async-shell-command "cat")
     (while (get-buffer-process buf)
       (message "still has proc")
       (kill-process (get-buffer-process buf))))
```

Comment: You should use `when`, not `while`.

Comment: I expect the loop condition will eventually evaluate to nil, why it does not is my question

Comment: I don't think that `kill-process` will unset the buffer's variable. Without testing, I'd guess that it will simply change status of the process to "exited" or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another attempt at explaining the situation:

```
(let ((buf "*Async Shell Command*"))
  (async-shell-command "cat")
  (while (let ((bp (get-buffer-process buf)))
           (message "status: %s" (process-status bp))
           bp)
    (message "still has proc")
    (kill-process (get-buffer-process buf))
    (accept-process-output)
    (message "Letting emacs to deal with closing a process")))
```

Then switch to the `*Messages*` buffer and look at the output, you should see:

```
status: run
still has proc
Letting emacs to deal with closing a process
status: signal
still has proc
cat: killed.
Letting emacs to deal with closing a process
Entering debugger...
```

#### What I believe is happening:

When Emacs starts a process, it sets its hooks for processing its events.  A hook dealing with event related to killing the process needs to run in the same thread in which your `while` loop is executing, but, unless `while` yields (it may sleep for example), Emacs will not be able to execute the hook.  So it will appear as if the process is still there.  This is very similar to the typical problems in cooperative multitasking schemes, where processes must make room for other processes to run, or otherwise some processes will never get the possibility to execute.

Comment: +1. For anyone interested, compare [`kill-process`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Signals-to-Processes.html#Signals-to-Processes), which merely signals the process, with [`delete-process`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Deleting-Processes.html#Deleting-Processes), which immediately disconnects Emacs from the process.

Answer (score 0):

`kill-process` is working in your case. But for a reason `get-buffer-process` does not return nil to `while`. Maybe because it refers to a buffer which is not yet closed, and emacs needs to take a breath? A `sit-for` command will fix this.

A solution would be:

```
(let ((buf
       "*Async Shell Command*"))
  (async-shell-command "cat")
  (while (get-buffer-process buf)
    (message "still has proc")
    (kill-process (get-buffer-process buf))
    (sit-for 0.01)))
```

Another solution could be not to use `get-buffer-process`:

```
(let ((buf
          "*Async Shell Command*"))
     (async-shell-command "cat")
     (while (not (string= (kill-process buf) buf))
       (message "still has proc")))
```

Comment: In my case `get-buffer-process` never returns `nil` within a loop that doesn't call `sit-for`. Try it yourself: `(progn (start-process "p" "b" "cat") (dotimes (i 10) (message "> %s" (get-buffer-process "b")) (kill-process "p")))`.

Comment: Basil, yes it looks like 'get-buffer-process' does not return nil with your code, even when counting to 1M. My second Solution is working completely without 'get-buffer-process'  But the questioneer asked 'why' not for a solution. :)

Comment: Sure, but it seems to me that in your answer both the "why" (`get-buffer-process` returns `nil`) and the "solution" (using `sit-for`) are wrong. What am I missing?

Comment: 1. Why is the solution to use 'sit-for' wrong?  2. The questioner asked why is the sexp hanging, so the reason is 'get-buffer-process is not returning nil', I edited my answer.

Comment: The explanation of wvxvw looks reasonable.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see your updated answer. The fact that `get-buffer-process` does not return `nil` is indeed the `why`, but I'm against referring to the use of `sit-for` as a `solution`. It merely points towards where the issue lies. A person facing this problem in their program would not solve it with `sit-for`; they would either avoid this situation altogether or do something like wvxvw suggests. I suggest you reword your answer to suggest `sit-for` as a means of clarifying what's happening, and not as a solution.